# C: Best way to read input file if only certain fields are fixed

Tags: c, fgets, scanf

Consider the given input:

```
ID    Name             Num
--------------------------

213DA Andrews, Dennis; 6.9      // <--- cursor initially located on 2
283JB Brown, Joanne; 2.6
420JB Brown, Joanne; 0.0
339VL Lee, Victor; 3.6
126RW White, D. Robert; 3.5
150JM Marcus, John; 4.0
// more data with same format as above
// EOF
```

I'd like to store each in parallel array of:

```
char *id[];
char *name[];
double num[];
```

Which one of the following is better?

1. LOOP (until EOF) {

   `fgets` to read the single line

   PARSE each fields.

   }
2. LOOP (until EOF) {

   `fscanf` to read `id[i]`

   `fscanf` to read `name[i]`

   `fscanf` to read `num[i]`

   i++

   }

Or, do we have more efficient (memory-wise and/or processing-speed-wise) way to write the code?

Comment: Any issues with busting the string using `strtok()`/`strtok_r()` after the `fgets()` ? your delimiters look pretty-well defined.

Comment: @WhozCraig I can use `strtok()` to locate the delimiters (by locating space, semicolon, and newline). This case, do I use `fgets` several times?

Comment: Thats you're call. If this is the format of the file through to the end, conceptually you could bulk load the whole file and `strtok()` parse it ad-nauseum. is the file this specified format from this point on to EOF?

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes. The input file follows this format until EOF. Instead of "bulk loading" the whole file, I can parse each fields after one single line read??

Comment: Sorry, had some stuff around the house to do. how you parse it is up to you (line by line, or one big huge read followed by a continual three-field strtok() loop until end-of-buffer, That would have potential advantages, especially if you just needed that static read. But whichever way you go, I think strtok()-ish parsing for this specific format, which as I said looks very well delimited, would probably work out pretty well for you.

Answer (score 0):

I reckon that the latter is better. Because it's more easy to read and more
straightforward. As for efficiency, I don't think the two methords have much difference, because the OS has done a lot for us. By the way, I suggest you use a struct type to make the code more readable.